# Should code to build views programmatically be put in UIView or UIViewController?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an app that has views that are build programmatically.  That is, I am fetching data from a database that contains information on things like the number, size and placement of buttons in a view. At some point, there will be code that uses this data to instantiate new  subviews and set them up.  My question is, where should this code go?  The view, the viewController, or somewhere else.  It seems to me that this is a grey area regarding typical MVC principles. Should a view accept data, and then know how to draw itself using this data?  Or perhaps, a viewController is responsible for building all the various subviews, and then simply adding them to the view.

Thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's a gray area.  Personally, I make a decision like that based on whether it's the data that needs manipulated or the display of that data.  For example, a view controller displaying a date may need to process various dates (ie, a data represented as a DMY struct vs. a date represented as a seconds count from some reference time) into a format suitable for the view, while the view itself may be only capable of receiving one particular format (ie, DMY) and is responsible for displaying that.  That's the sort of line I tend to draw between the two -- displaying data (the view) vs. interpreting data (the controller).

In your example of reconfiguring a view I would probably put most of the logic into the controller since it involves interpreting the data.  I would design the view to accept configuration details such as how many items to display and what sort of layout format to use (think of a UITableViewCell), but I would design the controller to interpret the data to decide how many items and what to put in the various fields within the view (like a UITableViewController).